# SOQL query aggregation

Tags: apex, soql, aggregate, group-by

I need to provide statistics to the users in my VF Page, showing the total of records they own where the status is **New**, **In progress**, **Approved**, **Pending**, **Converted**

I have tried the below query in my custom controller but I don't know how to combine different status's and I am getting an error

> Save error: Grouped field should not be aggregated: Status__c*

`Request_for_System_Change__c` is the name of the custom object

```
public list<Request_for_System_Change__c> getStats(){

RETURN  [
        SELECT 
            Count(Status__c)
            , MAX(Request_Title__c)
        FROM 
            Request_for_System_Change__c
        WHERE 
            ownerid=:userInfo.getUserID()
        GROUP BY 
            Status__c
        HAVING 
            Status__c='New'         
        ORDER by 
            MAX(LastModifiedDate) DESC
            ];  
}
```

Also, what is the best way to return this information - is a `<L:ist>` the way to go?

Comment: As the error says, you're using COUNT in the field that's in GROUP BY. Try Count(Id) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have posted should return a `List<AggregateResult>`, so it is unclear how you got it to compile. It seems you want something like the following:

```
public static Map<String, Integer> getMyRecordCounts()
{
    Map<String, Integer> recordCounts = new Map<String, Integer>();
    for (AggregateResult aggregate : [
        SELECT Status, count(Id) records FROM Request_for_System_Change__c
        WHERE OwnerId = :UserInfo.getUserId()
        GROUP BY Status
    ])
        recordCounts.put(
            (String)aggregate.get('Status'),
            (Integer)aggregate.get('records')
        );
    return recordCounts;
}
```